# php mail() won't send attachment over 10MB

Tags: apache, php

I have set these variables in `php.ini` but mail will not send an attachment over 10MB:

```
max_execution_time = 8000 ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 8000     ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 800M       ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

**Solved:**

The problem was solved by editing /etc/postfix/main.cf and making message_size_limit larger. Also, for those having problems with mail(), try "tail /var/log/mail.log" to see errors.

Comment: What about mail program used to send those emails? (MTA I think it's its designation.)

Comment: don't use php's mail() function uses something that creates a direct connection to the mail server.

Comment: How do you create attachments? Do you create MIME multipart manually? Are you using some other library?

Comment: I'm using the mail_attachment() someone made here: http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script

Answer (score 1):

Please see some examples / tutorial at [this link](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script).

This person makes a good point [here](http://forums.zpanelcp.com/thread-1033.html) that the mail server can set a limit on the attachment file size as well.

**Please read a very good point [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/27587/how-to-determine-a-reasonable-attachment-size-limit) about email not being a file transfer software!**

Comment: > This person makes a good point here that the mail server can set a limit on the attachment file size as well.
And most do, and 10M is pushing it for a lot of servers - is there any reason to mail out the attachment, vs. an HMAC'd link so they can download it normally?  In practice, there's not much difference in terms of speed, etc., and it's generally far more reliable.